# How can I transfter a libgdx project in eclipse from windows to linux and vice versa?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, libgdx

I have project in my Windows eclipse Luna IDE, that I would like to move it to my laptop that runs Linux. But I'm not sure how to do it. I'm exporting it in Windows as an archival file, but when I try to import it in my linux eclipse I get all sorts of errors. Does anyone have some insight on the process I need to follow?

Comment: Can't you just copy the project and related files to your Linux machine?

Comment: upload it to git and then pull at linux _/

Comment: Remove all .project and .classpath files in your projects. As well as the bin and .settings directories. Then just copy your project files to your linux machine and import the projects as gradle projects, the way you did the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have eclipse installed on your Linux machine, just copy the project folder from within your windows "Workspace" directory, and extract it to your "Workspace" directory on your linux machine. Once the files are copied, Go to:

File->Import->Existing Android Code Into Workspace

Browse to the newly copied project folder in your "Workspace" directory and check the box to "copy projects into workspace". You should be good to go, just be sure to double check your dependencies and any libraries that you have included in the build path and set an API target after import. Post your errors and it will be easier to figure out exactly what the issue is. It's probably just the dependencies and API target that need to be reassigned.